# Detect time from Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i hope this is the correct place to ask this. I'm working with a Wordpress theme which detects opening times of a business from a custom field, compares it to the current day and time and then displays a message to say if the business is currently open. This works perfectly in English, but when i change the site language to Spanish using qTranslate X Plugin, the business permanently appears as not open. I really have limited skills at this kinda thing, so i'm hoping someone can advise me.

From what i can see this is the js that does the comparison.

```
<?php 

/* ============== Check TIme ============ */

if (!function_exists('listingpro_check_time')) {
    function listingpro_check_time($postid,$status = false) {
        $output='';
        $buisness_hours = listing_get_metabox_by_ID('business_hours', $postid);

        if(!empty($buisness_hours)){
            if(!empty($postid)){
                $lat = listing_get_metabox_by_ID('latitude',$postid);
                $long = listing_get_metabox_by_ID('longitude',$postid);
            }

            //$timezone = getClosestTimezone($lat, $long);
            $timezone  = get_option('gmt_offset');
            $time = gmdate("H:i", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I"))); 
            $day =  gmdate("l");
            $time = strtotime($time);
            $lang = get_locale();
            setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang.'.utf-8');
            $day = strftime("%A");
            $day = ucfirst($day);
            foreach($buisness_hours as $key=>$value){
                if($day == $key){
                    $dayName = esc_html__('Today','listingpro');
                }else{
                    $dayName = $key;
                }
                $open = $value['open'];
                $open = str_replace(' ', '', $open);
                $close = $value['close'];
                $close = str_replace(' ', '', $close);
                $open = strtotime($open);
                $close = strtotime($close);
                $newTimeOpen = date('h:i A', $open);
                $newTimeClose = date('h:i A', $close);

                if($day == $key){
                    if($time > $open && $time < $close){
                        if($status == false){
                            $output = '<span class="grid-opened">'.esc_html__('Open Now~','listingpro').'</span>';
                        }else{
                            $output = 'open';
                        }
                    }else{
                        if($status == false){
                        $output = '<span class="grid-closed">'.esc_html__('Closed Now!','listingpro').'</span>';
                        }else{
                            $output = 'close';
                        }
                    }                               
                }                               

            }
        }else{
            if($status == true){
                $output = 'open';
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would language affect a custom field? A custom field is a custom field, the reference would be the same in English, Spanish, Swahili or Martian.

Comment: What is the output if you use `get_post_meta($postid, 'business_hours')`?

Comment: The language is not affecting the custom field, the custom field is being output correctly on the front in both languages. The part that is being affected is the automatic detection of whether the business is open or not. I believe the script uses the Wordpress timezone to work out if the business is open or not, but when i change the language i believe the timezone may be being changed too .. That's all i can think of.